# How to clean up *.osm.pbf files (Removing unwanted nodes, relationships, ways) with osmosis or osmium

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, openstreetmap, osmosis, osmium

I've recently began to dig deeper into manipulation raw osm data and later convert them to *.mbtiles to serve vector tiles to my web application. As the map only needs to be of low detail (is mainly used for displaying aviation data), I don't need buildings but want to keep some details (parks, airports, waterways etc. for aesthetic reasons).

So far I've tried using osmium and osmosis with okayish results. It still takes forever processing just one country (I'd need the whole of europe for now).
Removing buildings in osmosis produces a smaller file than in osmium? Probably my settings are wrong. Maybe there's even an other tool which might be better for the job?

Can you please point me in the right direction? I think having streets, water, airports placelabels and parks/forests present would be sufficient for now.

So far I've tried it with the commands below which still takes forever to import with openmaptiler in a c4.large instance on aws.

```
osmosis --read-pbf germany.osm.pbf --tf reject-ways building=* --used-node --write-pbf germany-wo-buildings.osm.pbf
```

My second approach was using osmium

```
osmium tags-filter -i germany.osm.pbf nrw/building=* -o germany-wo-buildingsg.osm.pbf
```

I'd really appreciate some help here to get a better understanding of working with osm data.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not really a programming question. Try asking at https://help.openstreetmap.org/ or https://gis.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I can see where you're coming from but for me it's programming related. I've also seen bash/python scripts for cleaning that stuff up. A mbtiles file is technically sqlite. I am not quite sure if the above problem can be solved just by running one cli tool. So I guess there are multiple steps to tackle the above problem. Thanks for the links though.

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution ? I am trying to generate the same type of data as you do by using osmium.